# Get all HTML-structure with "infinity" html page

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I get all HTML structure with "infinity" HTML page, using python and without using webdriver. By "infinity" HTML page I mean a page where new elements are loaded after user scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infinite scrolling sites (like Twitter) has javascript code that sends a request to their server for whatever needs to be added to the page, then manipulates the HTML on the fly to show the data. This setup is called AJAX, if you want to read more about it.

In order to get all the html data with this kind of setup, you have to locate the HTTP request object that is requesting the HTML data to be added to the infinite scrolling page. Then, you can simply call this request object with your program and get the data directly. You can find a good guide for how to set this up here:

https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/06/22/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros-june-2016/